# Form Submit - Populate Title Before Validation

Tags: 7, forms

I have no idea why I cannot find an answer to this.  I've been able to do this with other fields except the 'title' field.

I have a form which I need to automatically populate the title field.  I don't want the user to populate it, so I'm hiding it by wrapping it in a  that's hidden.

I used hook_form_alter() to add a callback function to the form's #submit array, but those functions are called after the validation.  This would result in an error telling the user to enter a title.

Now I'm trying to use hook_form_alter and adding a validation callback function to the BEGINNING of the array like so:

```
function previous_meetings_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)
{
    //Hide the title field
    $form['title']['#prefix'] = '<div style="display: none;">';
    $form['title']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    //Callback function to execute before validation
    array_unshift($form['#validate'], '_previous_meetings_set_meeting_title');
}
```

Here is the callback function that is being called but NOT working:

```
function _previous_meetings_set_meeting_title(&$form, &$form_state)
{
    $form_state['values']['title'] = 'SOMETHING';
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Can I set values in a validation callback?  Is there a right approach to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which form are you altering? Is the title field a field API field, or a normal form field?

Comment: Try [Automatic Nodetitles][1] module that may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `#prefix` and `#suffix` with `display:none`, it is hidden in display, but submitted and will be validated for required.
Try to use `#required = FALSE` and `#type = 'hidden'` and then set title in your submit handler.

```
function previous_meetings_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)
{
    // Hide the title field
    $form['title']['#required'] = FALSE;
    $form['title']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    // Callback function to execute before validation
    array_unshift($form['#submit'], '_previous_meetings_set_meeting_title');

}
```

And you could also use [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) with which you may use token replacement.

Comment: I submitted my answer before seeing this (it wouldn't let me answer it since I'm new).  Your solution similar to mine though.  Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind...got it. My solution:

```
function previous_meetings_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)
{
     $form['title']['#required'] = FALSE;
     $form['title']['#prefix'] = '<div style="display: none;">';
     $form['title']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
     $form['#submit'][] = '_previous_meetings_set_meeting_title';
}

function _previous_meetings_set_meeting_title(&$form, &$form_state)
{
    $form_state['values']['title'] = 'SOMETHING';
}
```